# Select data above and below row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to display a snippet of a football league table on a webpage.
I would like it to select one particular team (team b) and then the team one place above and one below.

eg.

```
              p  w  d  l
    team c    1  1  0  0
    team b    1  0  1  0
    team a    1  0  0  1
```

The following week it could be:

```
              p  w  d  l
    team d    2  2  0  0
    team b    2  1  1  0
    team c    2  1  0  1
```

and so on.

How would one best best going about this? Is it using query in MySQL or would I be looking to do it within PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Is then number of play In any given week is same for all the team?

Comment: What is the criteria for ranking the teams?

Comment: teams are ranked in order of points then goal difference, goals for then team name. I no these are outlined in the question above but was looking for how it culd be done and going by the answers so far wasn't to far away.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from games order by w;
+--------+------+------+------+------+
| name   | p    | w    | d    | l    |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
| team b |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
| team a |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
| team c |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
| team d |    2 |    2 |    0 |    0 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT NAME,P,W,D,L,@curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank FROM
```

(select NAME,P,W,D,L from games order by w DESC) x,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r;

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| NAME   | P    | W    | D    | L    | rank |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| team d |    2 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
| team c |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    2 |
| team b |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    3 |
| team a |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    4 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)


    mysql> SELECT NAME,P,W,D,L,rank FROM 
(SELECT NAME,P,W,D,L,@curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank,
if(name ="team b",@curRank := @curRank*-1,0)  AS required_rank 
FROM (select NAME,P,W,D,L from games order by w DESC) x,
(SELECT @curRank := 0) r ) p order by abs(rank) desc limit 3;
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| NAME   | P    | W    | D    | L    | rank |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| team b |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    3 |
| team c |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    2 |
| team a |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |   -2 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```